# How can I use multiple controller methods on one page in Yii Framework?

Tags: frameworks, yii

I was wondering how I can render multiple controller methods while accessing only one controller (in Yii Framework). So for example "controller/SiteController.php" (method "actionIndex") is called in the browser.

- Witch first renders the output of "controller/UserController.php" (method "actionDetails" -> "views/user/details.php").
- And after that also renders the output of "controller/SiteController.php" (method "actionIndex" -> "views/site/index.php") for the rest of the page.

Hope someone can help? I'm still kinda new to Yii. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be done, afterall a action is also a function isn't it..so we can call it..

In your first action after its render..Make an instance of the desired controller, in your case SiteController, call member function of it, in your case `actionIndex()`.

```
Yii::import('application.controllers.SiteController');
$controller_instance = new SiteController("Site"); //string $id, CWebModule $module=NULL
$controller_instance->actionIndex();
```

[Controller construct documentation](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CController#__construct-detail)

**Ideally as a mvc practice you shouldn't do this, instead make separate ajax requests form the page to get the contents from separate actions..**

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I'm trying it out now but I can't seem to call a different controller then the one I'm currently working in: "include(SiteController.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory". When running "index.php/user/details". Do you have an idea of what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Thank you very much, that was the missing link. A question about the ajax request you suggested: wouldn't that make it request multiple url's from the client side browser? Do you have an example of this?

Comment: yes..it'll be multiple requests from browser..take facebook..do u think it loads all d stuff when u open facebook.com??? nope..it renders a page with most required stuff and loads rest of d stuff by ajax calls..